# Search matrix rows with OR instead of AND

Tags: matrix, search, dynamic

I've setup some time ago a search field for matrix like so

```
{matrix_field search:matrix_col_01="value"} {Title}... {/if}
```

But now i need to add an extra value from a checkbox

```
{matrix_field search:matrix_col_01="value_from_checkbox" search:matrix_col_02="value_from_checkbox"} 
     {Title}... 
{/if}
```

The problem now is i don't see any values unless checkboxes from matrix_col_01 AND matrix_col_02 are checked.

Is it possible to to have value_one AND/OR value_two ?

The reason why i need this is to return certain rows only that contain value_01 or value_02 , i don't want to show all rows in one time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to break it out into a regular conditional statement where the two search results are compared with the OR operator:

```
{if '{matrixfield search:matrix_col_01="value_from_checkbox"}' || '{matrixfield search:matrix_col_02="value_from_checkbox"}'}
    {title}
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi Ian thanks for the the answer, but this doesn't seem to work it returns nothing at all.  i've tried the following {matrixfield} {if ...} .. {/if} {/matrixfield} and {if ..} {matrixfield}..{/matrixfield}{/if} but still nothing

Comment: Perhaps also to know that i've done this {matrixfield search:column="checkbox_value" search:column="checkbox_value"} ... {/matrixfield} that does work if both values are true ofc